# How do i extract multiple tables(35-40 tables) from a html website into one excel file?

Tags: datatable, rpa, uipath

Currently, am trying to retrieve data from this page: https://www.hdb.gov.sg/cs/infoweb/residential/renting-a-flat/renting-from-the-open-market/rental-statistics , as you can see, there are 4 quarters in a year, and for each quarter, there is a different table. I wish to extract the table but currently, i am unable to automate the process, only able to take one. On top of that, i wish to add two columns to the retrieved data table which is "Quarter" and "Year". Any suggestions? Attached photos are my workflow and my excel.
[image: Workflow part 1]
[image: Workflow part 2]
[image: Workflow part 3]
[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Get the number of years/ loop through the years (or start with the 1st year up to the last year).
For each year try to get the data via data scraping (the elements exist, just hidden/not expanded ; do one table datascraping for data modelling and reuse it within the loop). For the datascraping you need to change the selector, to make it usable for all tables by using the year and the quarter (just a generic example, like * year * quarter *). Columns are the same for all tables.

- I haven't seen details within the website menu or within the page, is good to check if robots are allowed to scrape for data
- Above would be the quickest way. More complex with FindChidren activity.